# Is there a Linux distro geared to ebook users?

Tags: linux

Is there a Linux distro that includes specialized tools for ebook authors and readers?

Comment: what's a "specialized tool for ebook readers"? Besides this, I think a better question should have been "is there a set of specialized tools to be installed on any Linux distro?"

Comment: This question appears to be too narrow in scope

Answer (score 7):

[Greenie](http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenie/) is an Lubuntu spin that works with standard Ubuntu repositories.

It comes with a set of pre-installed apps for ebook readers and authors, including:

- GWrite: Simple GTK+ HTML5 Rich Text Editor
- PDF Mod: Remove, extract, rotate pages
- Sigil: ePub file editor
- E-book Viewer
- FBReader
- Calibre

The default language is Slovak, but experienced linux users will have no trouble installing Greenie and switching the installation and system language to English (or any other language).

Afte‌r installation, you will still need to use Keyboard Input Methods to switch the keyboard to your preferred language. I also had to add the Mozilla English add-on for browser spell-checking.

Windows users can try a linux distro in a live session without changing their hard drive.

If you have never installed a linux distro before, you can find lots of answers at AskUbuntu that apply to any Ubuntu-based distro about how to burn an iso to disk or usb and how to do an installation.

(But please note that Ubuntu-based installations such as Greenie are *off-topic* as such at AskUbuntu.)

When you boot Greenie, the first option translates to Try Greenie without Installing, the second to Install Greenie.

The easiest way to switch the language for experimenting with the live distro is to:

1. Choose the 2nd option to install
2. Choose your language in the next screen
3. Cancel the installation

This will drop you into the Try without Installing option, but with your preferred language as the system language.

You can then change the keyboard from Menu >> Preferences >> Keyboard Input Methods.

(I have no connection to the Greenie project.)